# Adding a variable object

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I'm trying to add an object based on the level number. I've got the following declaration:

```
var lvlmapping:Object;
```

Later on, I run the following code:

```
if (levelnr == 1)
    lvlmapping= new lvl1map();
if (levelnr == 2)
    lvlmapping= new lvl2map();
if (levelnr == 3)
    lvlmapping= new lvl3map();
lvlmapping.x = 0;
lvlmapping.y = 0;
this.addChild(lvlmapping);
trace("Added mapping");
```

The following error pops up:

> Implicit coercion of a value of type static Object to a possible unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObject

What can I do to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `lvl1map` and the others are assets you will need to use `DisplayObject`,`Sprite` or `MovieClip` and not `Object`. So try changing :

```
var lvlmapping:Object;
```

to :

```
var lvlmapping:DisplayObject;
```

Comment: Or simply `var lvlmapping:*;`.

Comment: Nice catch! I'll accept it tomorrow since I have to wait for a long time now, you were too fast ;)

Comment: Actually, in my case, things still crashed when doing a collision detection. That problem was solved by using `MovieClip` instead. Thanks again!

Comment: He answered correctly, that's a different issue. Your collision detection likely required a MovieClip method, but that's a separate issue.